# gdb Runtime error : cannot locate file, overflow error : int too big to convert

Tags: gdb

I am getting this error message when running GDB.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                               
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1350, in __call__ 
    return self.lookup[basename].invoke(val)                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1287, in invoke
    return self.function(self.name, value)                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1045, in __init__
    func = gdb.block_for_pc(int(mgr.cast(gdb.lookup_type('intptr_t'))))                                 
RuntimeError: Cannot locate object file for block.
```

GDB is not working properly.. It was OK until some days ago. So I think some upgrade or something went wrong.

What could be the reason?

additional info :
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
libstdc++.so.6.0.25
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Comment: "What could be the reason?" -- something went wrong (_obviously_). You didn't supply *any* relevant info (version of GDB, GCC, `libstdc++`, etc.) so I doubt anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I added some more info. thanks.

Comment: You have `g++ 7.5` and `/usr/share/gcc-8/python/...` That *could be* a problem.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your gdb linked against Python 2, or Python 3?  I'm going to guess Python 2, and that this is a buglet in the libstdc++ pretty-printers, and that they should be changed to cast to `long` here.